# Why my VS 2008 will be closed down when try to edit some ASPX file from Nerddinner Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, nerddinner

Why my VS 2008 will be closed down when try to open or edit the .ASPX files from Nerddinner Project?

I'm using VS 2008 Professional SP1 version.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What do you mean "close down"... is there an error message?

Comment: there is no error messages and it just disappears (closed).

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the reason. I changed the name of the controller.